# iterating through an array - getting duplicate values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to setup a scheduled task on heroku that runs through an array of user ids and executes a method using that user id like so:

```
def self.worker_populate_google_stats
   users = ["5", "6", "8"]
   date_object = Date.today - 1

   users.each do |e|
      date = date_object.strftime("%Y%m%d")
      user = User.find(e)
      GoogleRecord.get_and_create(user, date)
   end
end
```

It successfully executes the get_and_create method but it gives identical output for each user as though it ran it with the same id over and over.

What am I missing here?

---

**update**

If I were to run the following in the console, passing a different id into `User.find()` I would in fact get the proper, unique output so I feel confident the issue isn't in the method.

```
user = User.find(5)
date_object = Date.today - 1
date = date_object.strftime("%Y%m%d")
GoogleRecord.get_and_create(user, date)
```

Comment: Try to put e into log Rails.logger.debug(e) and make sure that id is always appropriate

Comment: `but it gives identical output for each user ` What does that mean? Can you clarfiy EXACTLY what the issue is please. Also what class is this method in? Have you a users method or variable defined in it elsewehere

Comment: What happens if you use a variable name other than users

Comment: Thanks jamesw - the output is an array of hashes from an api call that all end up being identical.  They should be different as each user has different credentials.  Essentially the block runs and passes the first item in the array each time for the `user` argument in `get_and_create` method

Comment: you were missing an `end` statement for the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this, maybe, instead:

```
users = User.find([5, 6, 8])
date = (Date.today - 1).strftime("%Y%m%d")

users.each do |user|
  GoogleRecord.get_and_create(user, date)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Brad, but it still runs GoogleRecord passing "5" in for `user` 3 times

Comment: Try throwing a `p user` in the first line of the block, and see what comes out... Do you override `to_params`? You may have to paste the code of your `get_and_create` method.

Comment: While not the final answer, this did help lead me to the solution.  Ultimately there was a method within the `get_and_create` method that had `@api ||= create_adwords_api(request_params)` in it.  When it was running for one user, it was creating an new api object with the credentials.  When running for any subsequent users, it was utilizing the already created API object and giving the duplicate stats (output).